# Create an XSD example - Hours of Operation - One of Several Types

Tags: xml, xsd

An example of some XML that could be sent:

```
<hours-of-operation>
        <monday hourType="custom">
            <open unit="AM">9:00</open> <!-- open/close or closed or 24hour -->
            <close unit="PM">5:00</close>
        </monday>
        <tuesday hourType="closed" />
        <wednesday hourType="24hour" />
        <thursday hourType="custom">
            <open unit="AM">9:00</open> <!-- open/close or closed or 24hour -->
            <close unit="PM">5:00</close>
        </thursday>
        <friday hourType="custom">
            <open unit="AM">9:00</open> <!-- open/close or closed or 24hour -->
            <close unit="PM">5:00</close>
        </friday>
        <saturday hourType="closed" />
        <sunday hourType="closed" />
    </hours-of-operation>
```

I want **an XSD that defines the hours of operations element**.  If it makes things simpler, feel free to make the `hourType` an element as opposed to an attribute.

So basically, I need a day for each week, and it can EITHER have open and close hours, be closed, or be open 24 hours.  Also, the requirements here are not lenient, I require all days of the week.

If it weren't clear, I don't want to know how you'd approach this problem in practice.  I want XSD definitions for the XML that I posted, if you have a source that attempts to tackle this problem I want the specific XSD portion that applies exactly to this XML.  I don't know much about XML schemas, and while I'm learning best I can quickly, the best thing I can get for this is the actual XSD code for this use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would have been an acceptable answer, it doesn't validate that the time is time at all, it's just a string, but for the example posted would work.

```
<xs:element name="hours-of-operation">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="monday" type="day-hours"/>
                <xs:element name="tuesday" type="day-hours"/>
                <xs:element name="wednesday" type="day-hours"/>
                <xs:element name="thursday" type="day-hours"/>
                <xs:element name="friday" type="day-hours"/>
                <xs:element name="saturday" type="day-hours"/>
                <xs:element name="sunday" type="day-hours"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:complexType name="day-hours">
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:element name="twentyfourhours"/>
            <xs:element name="closed"/>
            <xs:element name="hours" type="hours"/>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="hours">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="open" type="time"/>
            <xs:element name="close" type="time"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="time">
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute name="unit" use="required" type="unit"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
```